# Error using __ldg in cuda kernel at compile time

Tags: c++, cuda

My goal is to take advantage of cache memory in my application and searching for online examples shows that using `__ldg` should be relatively straightforward.

`NVIDIA` has documentation for `GPU` optimization (found here: https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/GPU_Opt_Fund-CW1.pdf) which provides the straightforward example:

```
__global__ void kernel ( int *output, int *input)
{
  ...
  output[idx] = __ldg( &input[idx] );
}
```

However when I try to compile this I get the following error message:

```
error: identifier "__ldg" is undefined.
```

Searching Google for a solution to this error message has been unfortunately unhelpful.  Any suggestions what may be wrong with this simple example?
Is there a compiler flag that I am missing?

For reference my device is compute capability 3.5 and I am working with `CUDA 5.5`.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your compile command line?  To take advantage of a cc3.5 device, you need to compile for that architecture with `-arch=sm_35` or similar.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this was the issue. I was using sample code from nVidia and their makefile calls multiple flags and I thought it would just use the highest capability available, but removing the lower compute capability flags resulted in correct compilation. Thanks.

Comment: @user3280204 if compiling for the correct architecture solved the problem, I believe you should accept the answer given below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `__ldg()` [intrinsic](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#ldg-function) is only available on compute capability 3.5 (or newer) architecture.

That means:

1. It must be run on a compute 3.5 (or newer) GPU
2. It must be compiled for a compute 3.5 (or newer) GPU
3. It cannot also be compiled for an older architecture.

That means:

1. This won't work:  `nvcc -arch=sm_30 ...`
2. This will work: `nvcc -arch=sm_35 ...`
3. This won't work: `nvcc -gencode arch=compute30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 ...`

Answer (score 7):

For an implementation of `__ldg` that generalizes to arbitrary types and correctly falls back on compute capability less than 3.5, see the [BryanCatanzaro/generics](https://github.com/BryanCatanzaro/generics) Github project.

Here is a bare bones template:

```
template<typename T>
__device__ __forceinline__ T ldg(const T* ptr) {
#if __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 350
    return __ldg(ptr);
#else
    return *ptr;
#endif
}
```

Comment: But ```template<typename T>
__device__ __forceinline__ T __ldg(const T* ptr) {```