# What is the difference between __ldg() intrinsic and a normal execution?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to explore '__ldg intrinsic'. I have gone through NVIDIA's documentation for this but didn't get any satisfactory answer over its use and implementations. Moreover with reference to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069524/error-using-ldg-in-cuda-kernel-at-compile-time/24073775#24073775) I tried implementing __ldg in a simple 1024*1024 matrix multiplication example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

__global__ void matrix_mul(float * ad,float * bd,float * cd,int N)
{
        float pvalue=0;
        //find Row and Column corresponding to a data element for each thread
        int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
        int Col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        //calculate dot product of Row of First Matrix and Column of Second Matrix
        for(int i=0;i< N;++i)
        {
//   I tried with executing this first:
            float m=__ldg(&ad[Row * N+i]);
            float n=__ldg(&bd[i * N + Col]);

//Then I executed this as a normal execution:
//          float m = ad[Row * N+i];
//          float n = bd[i * N + Col];

            pvalue += m * n;
         }
        //store dot product at corresponding position in resultant Matrix
        cd[Row * N + Col] = pvalue;
}

int main()
{
    int N = 1024,i,j;               //N == size of square matrix

    float *a,*b;
    float *ad,*bd,*cd,*c;

    //open a file for outputting the result
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("Parallel Multiply_ldg.txt","w");

    size_t size=sizeof(float)* N * N;

    //allocate host side memory
    a=(float*)malloc(size);
    b=(float*)malloc(size);
    c=(float*)malloc(size);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            a[i*N+j]=2.0;   //(float)(i*N+j);       //initializing each value with its own index
            b[i*N+j]=1.0;   //(float)(i*N+j);       //random functions can be used alternatively
        }
    }

    //allocate device memory
    cudaMalloc(&ad,size);
    //printf("\nAfter cudaMalloc for ad\n%s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
    cudaMalloc(&bd,size);
    //printf("\nAfter cudaMalloc bd\n%s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
    cudaMalloc(&cd,size);
    //printf("\nAfter cudaMalloc cd\n%s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));

    //copy value from host to device
    cudaMemcpy(ad,a,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(bd,b,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    printf("\nAfter HostToDevice Memcpy\n%s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));

    //calculate execution configuration
    dim3 blocksize(16,16);              //each block contains 16 * 16 (=256) threads
    dim3 gridsize(N/16,N/16);           //creating just sufficient no of blocks

    //GPU timer code
    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start,stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start,0);

    matrix_mul <<< gridsize, blocksize >>> (ad,bd,cd, N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time,start,stop);         //time taken in kernel call calculated
    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);

    //copy back results
    cudaMemcpy(c,cd,sizeof(float)* N*N,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("\nAfter DeviceToHost Memcpy\n%s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));

    //output results in output_file
    fprintf(f,"Array A was---\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            fprintf(f,"%f ",a[i*N+j]);
        fprintf(f,"\n");
    }
    fprintf(f,"\nArray B was---\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            fprintf(f,"%f ",b[i*N+j]);
        fprintf(f,"\n");
    }
    fprintf(f,"\nMultiplication of A and B gives C----\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            fprintf(f,"%f ",c[i*N+j]);              //if correctly computed, then all values must be N
        fprintf(f,"\n");
    }
    printf("\nYou can see output in Parallel Mutiply.txt file in project directory");
    printf("\n\nTime taken is %f (ms)\n",time);
    fprintf(f,"\n\nTime taken is %f (ms)\n",time);
    fclose(f);

    cudaThreadExit();
    //cudaFree(ad); cudaFree(bd); cudaFree (cd);
    free(a);free(b);free(c);
    //_getch();
    return 1;
}
```

I commented that __ldg part in my kernel and executed by normal execution, and vice versa.
In both cases it gives me correct multiplication result. I am confused with the time difference I am getting between these executions, because its huge almost more than 100X!

In case of __ldg it gives me: `Time taken is 0.014432 (ms)`

And in case of normal execution without __ldg it gives me : `Time taken is 36.858398 (ms)`

Is this the exact way of using __ldg intrisic? What is the significance of __ldg intrinsic and what is the proper way of using it? Apparently what I did above in my code is wrong and naive. I am looking for explanation and example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just so I understand this - the results are correct, you got a large speed up, and your question is "what did I do wrong?"?....

Comment: @talonmies The speed is so large that I doubt if this correct. And if this is correct then what magic this __ldg does that I am getting this speedup? And if this is incorrect then what is correct way to use __ldg? Overall I am looking for more explanation on this __ldg concept and its implementation.

Comment: I assume you checked the result against a CPU result. njuffa supplied [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/638031/cuda-programming-and-performance/ldg-versus-textures/post/4013321/#4013321) explanation vis-a-vis the mechanism. It really boils down to reducing the memory access latency, removing a bottleneck.

Comment: @AviGinsburg No! These both are GPU results. One is with using __ldg and other is without using __ldg

Comment: You wrote "In both cases it gives me exact multiplication result." I assumed you verified the results against a third party result, but even against each other, why do you still doubt the `ldg` result? As to the "magic," at the risk of repeating myself, it's caching the memory access which removes the bottleneck.

Comment: You may want to try without `__ldg` the following signature `__global__ void matrix_mul(__restrict__ float const* ad, __restrict__ float const* bd,float * cd,int N)`

Comment: @Cicada, that would result in a *suggestion* to the compiler to cache `ad` and `bd`, as opposed to the explicit `ldg`.

Comment: @AviGinsburg With 'Exact' result I meant to say the correct result. See, I was surprised only because of the speedup I achieved here, which is more than 100X, using a single keyword only, which quite hard to believe! We put so much efforts in shared memory programming to achieve speedup, and here I am getting it using __ldg only. So wanted to understand logic behind this. Thanks for your answer by the way, its useful.

Comment: @Avi Yes, that's the goal.

Comment: what GPU are you running this comparison on?

Comment: In fact the speedup you're reporting is on the order of 2500x and is not sensible.  The 36ms number seems reasonable, as I get ~17ms for your code as-is on a K40c GPU.  The 0.0144ms number is not reasonable.  I suspect that the kernel launch is failing, perhaps due to the type of GPU you are running on (if it is not a cc3.5 GPU, the launch will fail) and the result is this very short measurement.  Of course, your claim in that case that "the results are correct" cannot be the case.  Perhaps you are looking at an old output data file. (And also not noticing the error reported by your code.)

Comment: @RobertCrovella Exactly!I completely agree with you. And this is the main I posted this question here. I am using Tesla C2075 and Quadro 600 on a single machine. And as you can see in my code I am writing results in separate files for every execution. Funny part is the result is correct, and making me more confused!

Comment: @RobertCrovella My mistake!! None of them has compute capability 3.5 :-( . Although I gave reference of one of your answers and posted this question, I missed this important point of cc. I will execute this on the required GPU(cc 3.5) and get back here to close this question.

Comment: The result is not correct.  When you run this code on either of the GPUs you mentioned, it will print out "invalid device function" but you seem to be ignoring that.  And your claim that the results are correct is also not true.  Probably you are confused and did not change the file name when you recompiled the code.  `__ldg` requires compute capability 3.5

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-3-0)

> Global memory accesses for devices of compute capability 3.x are cached in L2 and for devices of compute capability 3.5, may also be cached in the read-only data cache described in the previous section; they are not cached in L1.

...

> Data that is read-only for the entire lifetime of the kernel can also be cached in the read-only data cache described in the previous section by reading it using the `__ldg()` function (see Read-Only Data Cache Load Function). When the compiler detects that the read-only condition is satisfied for some data, it will use `__ldg()` to read it. The compiler might not always be able to detect that the read-only condition is satisfied for some data. Marking pointers used for loading such data with both the `const` and `__restrict__` qualifiers increases the likelihood that the compiler will detect the read-only condition.

The read only cache accesses have a much lower latency than the global memory accesses. Because matrix multiplication accesses the same values from memory many times, caching in the read only cache gives a huge speedup (in memory bound applications).

Comment: What if the input data is big? Here in my example I have two arrays of type float of size 1024. Lets consider the size is in millions and there are multiple arrays. In that case the whole data cannot be cached, right? Would __ldg be applicable in this case?

Comment: @sandeep.ganage I honestly don't know. My gut would be to say it would help, because at worst, it's a cache miss. I would then benchmark it. After that, I would probably use cublas.

Comment: @sandeep.ganage After looking at [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/kepler-tuning-guide/index.html#read-only-data-cache) again, it should work for large matrices as well. It is similar to using textures, just without the need to actually use textures.

Comment: @sandeep.ganage Caches of any kind, on CPUs or GPUs, rely on data re-use as well as spatial and temporal locality to provide performance benefits. The typical case of cache use involves data structures much bigger (by orders of magnitude even) than the size of the cache. Generally, as long as there is both locality of accesses and data re-use, the cache will provide a performance benefit. There are some exceptions to this, look up "cache thrashing".

Answer (score 2):

In NVIDIA GPU there is a texture - images with special and not hard logic to work with images.

This **texture memory** is another type of memory available in GPU. In particularly constant, global and register file memory has not any relation to this texture memory.

Kepler GPUs and later add the ability to use this memory from "GPU texture pipeline".

But let's specify the difference between constant cache and read-only cache.

**Constant Cache**

Data loaded through the constant cache must be relatively small and must be accessed in such way that all threads of a warp should access the same location at any given time.

**Read-only Cache or Texture Memory Cache**

Cache can be much larger and can be accessed in a non-uniform pattern.
Read Only cache has granularity 32 bytes.

---

You can use this as "read-only cache" for your CUDA kernel.

```
1. Data stored in global memory can be cached in that place GPU Texture Memory
2. With doing that you give promise to the compiler that data is read-only for the 
   duration of a kernel execution in GPU.
```

There are two ways to achieve this.

**A.** Using an intrinsic function __ldg

```
Example: output[i] += __ldg(&input[j]);
```

**B.** Qualifying pointers to global memory

```
const float* __restrict__ input
output[idx] += input[idx];
```

**Comparision:**

The intrinsic __ldg is a better choice for deep compiler reasons.